# Side bands with different color in UITableviewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios6

I just added the backgroundColor to my cell and this happened:

[image]

I'm just wondering how those two bands appeared in my cell. The code I used to add the background is this:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (indexPath.row % 2) {
        [cell setBackgroundColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:48/255.0 green:83/255.0 blue:129/255.0 alpha:0.1]];
    }
}
```

Comment: your are changing the alpha, which in the reference doc for the delegate method you are using says you should not do (it gets changed right back). Does this happen when leaving the alpha to 1?

Comment: Hi Hermione333, I'm so sorry, but this viewController has been changed a zillion times since November and I can't reproduce anymore this bug :( Thank you anyway for your answer, probably it is correct!